# CSS issue: why the 100% width plus 1px border fall in FF browser but not in Chrome?

Tags: css

I use **1140px cssgrid.net framework**, i use 12 cols in the content, 2cols for sidebar and 10cols and put border-right: 1px in sidebar, why the 10col fall in FF browser but not in Crhome?
Mark-up:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="twocols"></div>
<div id="main_content" class="tencols"></div>
```

Styles:

```
#sidebar { border-right: 1px solid red }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be you have to define `box-sizing` to it. It's work in all browsers.

```
#sidebar { 
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
 }
```